# Pricing American with floating strike

Tags: option-pricing, american-options

Consider a American floating strike put option with maturity $T$, written on a non-dividend paying stock $S_t$. The strike of this option at time $t\leq T$ is $Ke^{-r (T-t )}$, where $r$ is the constant interest rate.

Assume the volatility of the underlying stock is constant.

What is the price of this option?

Comment: Hi ABC, welcome to Quant.SE and thank you for asking your question here. Can you show us what you have tried?

Comment: @BobJansen I did. You need to meditate why that type of request makes no sense and actually harms these Q-A websites.

Answer (score 5):

These options can be priced by adding an early exercise premium value to the intrinsic value:

https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.542.3141&rep=rep1&type=pdf

Comment: I had the same question, but unfortunately the link in the answer is meanwhile dead.
Does anyone have an answer for this?

Comment: I believe it to be [this article](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.542.3141&rep=rep1&type=pdf).